# Obtain a substring that occurs multiple times?

Tags: java, string, substring

```
String str="The colors are [blue], [yellow], and [green]";
```

I have seen many posts how to achieve this using regex.

```
Here is my for loop that keeps giving me a string out of range error:
   for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
      String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.indexOf("]"));
      System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: So you fetch what is between the first occurrence of `[` and the first occurrence of `]`. Why should it fetch all of them?

Comment: To get an *unknown* number of *something*, you'd likely need a loop.

Comment: for (int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
      String result = str.substring(str.indexOf("[") + 1, str.indexOf("]"));
      System.out.println(result); }

Comment: What do you think `indexOf` does? Hint: my last comment mentioned "first".

Comment: Does it only get the index of the first occurrence? I thought that incrementing through the string using a for loop would work.

Comment: Why ask if you should use `charAt()` when you could just try?

Comment: Note that String.indexOf is overloaded: `public int indexOf(int ch, int fromIndex)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say you want something like that if you strictely don't want to use regex... for whatever reason. Regex will almost certainely be equally fast and the code looks much much nicer. But anyway here's a sample code how it would look like:

```
String str="The colors are [blue], [yellow], and [green]";

ArrayList<String> arr = new ArrayList<String>();

for(int i = str.indexOf('[', 0); i != -1; i = str.indexOf('[', i + 1)) {
    arr.add(str.substring(i + 1, str.indexOf(']', i)));
}

for(String s : arr) {
    System.out.println(s);
}
```